# Obtaining Facebook Page token via Facebook Graph Explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am trying to follow the steps on this page but using the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) instead: http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/obtaining-facebook-page-access-tokens-the-4-step-program/

Can someone help with steps in getting a permenant Page Token from the Graph Explorer? Some posts are outdated and referring to offline access. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: _“Some posts are outdated and referring to offline access.”_ – well then go and read up on it in the _official documentation_ for up-to-date information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is correct, i just tested it: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

See "Extended Page Access Token" in the article: Basically you have to authorize yourself with the "manage_pages" permission, then you need to extend your User Access Token, and with that Token you make a call to /me/accounts to get the Extended Page Access Tokens for all your pages.

Comment: Please not that link-only answers, or "See the ... section" answers are frowned upon.  You should include the relevant instructions in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS FOR LASTING PAGE ACCESS TOKEN**

1- You have to get page access token for a user by this API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{User-id}/accounts?access_token={access-token}
```

2- Then u have to  refresh the save token by below API which will last for 60 days:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={your-client-id}&client_secret={client-secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={previous-access-token}
```